# Connection refused in SoapU, but not python

Tags: ssl, soapui

I'm setting up a server with a couple of web services in Jboss 4.2.2. When I disable the SSL verification on the connector, all calls go through in SoapUI as well from a python script containing the same payload as the SoapUI script.

But when I enable the SSL verification with a connected keystore on the connector, all requests from SoapUI gets refused, with the following error:

```
Error getting response; org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://1...8:2443 refused
```

My python-script still runs and successfully recieves the response as expected.

I have also linked the same keystore to the SSL settings in SoapUI, but without luck. I'm not familiar enough with SoapUI to know what I'm missing.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

2443 isn't the default https connector port. Check it out on your server configuation. You can check the ports on which jboss is listening too using `netstat`, or directly use `telnet` to probe the connection.

Comment: It's true, it is not the default port, but I have changed the settings to publish the service on port 2443. And as the port works flawless without SSL, and only through curl and python with SSL enabled, I think the error is somewhere within SoapUI.

Comment: Edit your question, add the steps you did to set de client certificate in Soap UI (Global and per request configuration).